# Make the content area div come next the menu bar

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make content area appear on the right of the menu_bar](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6793/make-content-area-appear-on-the-right-of-the-menu-bar)

The following is the code i have written, this is the CSS part of it

```
body{
color:#000000;
font-family: arial, san serif;
```

}

## container {

```
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
width: 80%;
```

}

## header {

```
margin-left: 0.5%;
margin-right: 0.5%;
margin-top: 0.5%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
width: 99%;
height: 10%;
```

}

## pathway{

```
margin-left: 0.5%;
margin-right: 0.5%;
margin-top: 0.5%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
width: 99%;
height: 3.5%;
```

}

## menu_bar{

```
margin-left: 0.5%;
margin-right: 0.5%;
margin-top: 0.5%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
width: 20%;
height: 40%;
```

}

## content_area{

```
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 0.5%;
margin-top: 0.5%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
width: 20%;
height: 40%;
```

}

## footer

{
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    border: 1px solid #46A5E0;
    width: 99%;
    height: 3.5%;
}

This is making the content_area go below the menu_bar how do i bring it to the right of the menu bar.

Comment: This belogs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ and should be automatically migrated there soon.

Comment: Or perhaps [DocType](http://doctype.com/)

Comment: As per the Webmasters FAQ, I think doctype.com would be a better fit for this question.